# Does each KVM Guest need its own ISO

Tags: iso, kvm-virtualization

Does each KVM guest require its own copy of the bootable ISO image? If I'm thinking correctly, the guest only needs to read the .iso, not lock it or anything, so multiple guests should be able to use the same ISO. Or am I approaching the problem the wrong way?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course since isoes are read only, you could do as you suggest, but Ubuntu isoes allow an actual installation to the virtual disk, which does take more space (3-4G), but then the iso is not used at all, and since the filesystem is no longer compressed, should boot/run faster.